# Cannot delete Object from local AppEngine datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Hi I am using Objectify to manage the AppEngine Datastore. I have following object:

> ```
> public class Config implements Serializable{ @Id Long id ;}
> ```

I also have a repository which uses `ofy().get() and ofy().put()`:

```
public class ConfigRepo extends DAOBase{};
```

Note: This is for localhost

I deleted local_db.bin from the appengine-generated and cleared the memcache ass well. 
However when I try to run

> ofy.delete(allKeys)

to clear the datastore I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id cannot be zero
```

Or

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Config(no-id-yet) is incomplete.
```

What my I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

It turned out that there were two local_db.bin one in root/war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated and one in root/WEB-INF/appengine-generated
I had to delete local_db.bin from both of the locations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be somewhere in the code that initializes allKeys, you're not passing in the correct entity ids. Maybe you're generating the Keys before the entities are persisted and ids generated. If this doesn't help, please show the relevant parts of your code!

Comment: Turned out that there were two local_db.bin one in root/war/web-inf/appengine-generated and one in root/web-inf/appengine-generated I had to delete both of the local_db.bin and problem is gone. I am still wondering how this data is created since I am using the key auto generation feature meaning putting @id Long without any key for the first time.